# Tag [ad] should be merged with and made a synonym of tag [ads]

Tags: discussion, retag-request

[ad](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ad) should be merged with and made a synonym of [ads](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ads) - they both mean the same thing, one has an `s`, and one doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has now been completed. With [ads](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ads) being the parent tag.